# Pymongo Query Returns 0 Results Despite Data Being in Collection

Tags: flask, pymongo

My pymongo database has data in the collection I am querying, but it is returning 0 results when I run the query.

In the code below the count gives me 9 results, but the cursor returned to invites has 0 items in it.

```
@app.route("/myinvites", methods=["GET"])
@login_required
def myinvites():
    myid = current_user.get_id()
    invites = db.invite.find({"user_id":ObjectId(myid)})
    count = db.invite.find({"user_id":ObjectId(myid)}).count()
    print(count)
    print(invites.retrieved)
    return render_template("myinvites.html", myinvites = invites)
```

The output is as below:

9
0

I can't figure out what is happening, it seems strange as I am using the same type of query in other views and it is working.

Comment: It was just an error in my template, it is actually returning the data to the queryset. Should I be using invites.count() and not invites.retrieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS you mentioned in the edit, **.count()** returns the count of records returned by the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the count you can use

```
count = db.invite.count_documents({"user_id":ObjectId(myid)})
```

It's a bit more efficient.